# Need help populating jqGrid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, jqgrid, asp.net-ajax

I am having trouble simply populating the jqGrid with data. I have taken a look at the docs and hope that somebody can **please** help me out with this...

I have verified that data is coming back from my server side controller method as below. Sample is just for one for the records from the *fto* object.

```
Customer_Name = "X"
FuelTkt_ID = 2
Image_ID = "12345"
Ticket_No = 6460193
Trans_Timestamp = {3/19/2014 10:20:00 AM}
Vehicle_No = "123456"

public async Task<JsonResult> GetFilteredFuelTicketsAsync(HH_FuelTkt_Input id)
        {
            try
            {
                IEnumerable<HH_FuelTkt_Output> fto = await db.GetFilteredFuelTicketsAsync(id);

                return Json(fto, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                strRemedyTktResponse = IssueRemedyTicket("Class: FuelTktController" + CrLf + "Method: GetFilteredFuelTickets" + CrLf + "Error: " + ex.Message + CrLf + "InnerException: " + ex.InnerException + CrLf + "Source: " + ex.Source + CrLf + "StackTrace: " + ex.StackTrace);
                LogMessage.WriteEventLog("Class: FuelTktController" + CrLf + "Method: GetFilteredFuelTickets" + CrLf + "Error: " + ex.Message + CrLf + "InnerException: " + ex.InnerException + CrLf + "Source: " + ex.Source + CrLf + "StackTrace: " + ex.StackTrace, "FuelTktController", 1, strRemedyTktResponse);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

On my client side, I can see the data in my result. **Can somebody please tell me what I'm missing here in order to populate the grid???**
Below is my code for the grid and underneath that is the data coming back:

```
if (begDte <= endDte) {
                            $('#fuelTickets').jqGrid({
                                caption: "Fuel Tickets",
                                colModel: [
                                        { name: 'FuelTkt_ID', index: 'FuelTkt_ID', label: 'ID', width: 20, align: "right", editable: false },
                                        { name: 'Ticket_No', index: 'Ticket_No', label: 'Ticket', width: 60, align: "right", editable: false },
                                        { name: 'Customer_Name', index: 'Customer_Name', label: 'Customer', width: 150, editable: false },
                                        { name: 'Vehicle_No', index: 'Vehicle_No', label: 'Vehicle', width: 60, editable: false },
                                        { name: 'Trans_Timestamp', index: 'Trans_Timestamp', label: 'Date', width: 100, editable: false },
                                        { name: 'Image_ID', index: 'Image_ID', label: 'Image ID', width: 150, editable: false }
                                ],
                                pager: false,
                                viewRecords: true,
                                gridview: true,
                                autoWidth: true,
                                emptyRecords: "No records found",
                                onCellSelect: function (rowid, iCol, cellcontent) {
                                    var grid = $('#fuelTickets');
                                    var imageID = grid.jqGrid('getCell', rowid, 'Image_ID');
                                    if (imageID != "")
                                        DisplayReceipt(imageID);
                                }
                            })
                            var HH_FuelTkt_Input = {
                                Vehicle_No: $('#txtVehicleNbr').val(),
                                Customer_Name: $('#txtCustomerName').val(),
                                Trans_Timestamp_Begin: $('#dteBeginDate').val(),
                                Trans_Timestamp_End: $('#dteEndDate').val()
                            };
                            $.ajax({
                                url: '@Url.Action("GetFilteredFuelTicketsAsync")',
                                type: 'POST',
                                data: JSON.stringify(HH_FuelTkt_Input),
                                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                dataType: 'json',
                                success: function (result) {
                                    var grid = $("#fuelTickets");
                                    grid.clearGridData();
                                    grid.addRowData(result);
                                },
                                error: function (jqXHR, jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                    alert("No record found: " + "textStatus: " + textStatus + "\r\n" + "errorThrown: " + errorThrown);
                                }
                            });
                        }
```

Here is the data coming back:

```
[Object { FuelTkt_ID=2, Ticket_No=6460193, Vehicle_No="123456", more...}, Object { FuelTkt_ID=3, Ticket_No=6460194, Vehicle_No="123456", more...}]

0
    Object { FuelTkt_ID=2, Ticket_No=6460193, Vehicle_No="123456", more...}

1
    Object { FuelTkt_ID=3, Ticket_No=6460194, Vehicle_No="123456", more...}
```

Here are the individual records:

```
0
    Object { FuelTkt_ID=2, Ticket_No=6460193, Vehicle_No="123456", more...}

Customer_Name
    "X"

FuelTkt_ID
    2

Image_ID
    "12345"

Ticket_No
    6460193

Trans_Timestamp
    "/Date(1395238800000)/"

Vehicle_No
    "123456"

1
    Object { FuelTkt_ID=3, Ticket_No=6460194, Vehicle_No="123456", more...}

Customer_Name
    "X"

FuelTkt_ID
    3

Image_ID
    "22856"

Ticket_No
    6460194

Trans_Timestamp
    "/Date(1395246000000)/"

Vehicle_No
    "123456"
```

**Correct code that worked:**
Rather than dealing with the over complicated documentation about the "*header*" for the grid, the following solved **all** the issues without making **any** changes to my server code (no need to place any paging in here). It took just **one** statement to populate the grid that is never mentioned in the jqGrid documentation.

Actually, it **is** mentioned in the docs here, but is never used in an example which would have made it a lot easier to understand.

```
http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data
```

I am posting for all to see and to benefit from this lack of documentation and over complication of the header.

The most important statement in the js below which populates the grid is the following:

```
$("#fuelTicketsGrid")[0].addJSONData(data);
```

That's all it took!

**HTML**

```
<div>
                <table id="fuelTicketsGrid" class="table"></table>
                <div id="GridPager"></div>
            </div>
```

**JS**

```
function LoadGridData() {
                var HH_FuelTkt_Input = {
                    Vehicle_No: $('#txtVehicleNbr').val(),
                    Customer_Name: $('#txtCustomerName').val(),
                    Trans_Timestamp_Begin: $('#dteBeginDate').val(),
                    Trans_Timestamp_End: $('#dteEndDate').val()
                };
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetFilteredFuelTicketsAsync", "Home")',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: JSON.stringify(HH_FuelTkt_Input),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#fuelTicketsGrid")[0].addJSONData(data);
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert("No record found: " + "textStatus: " + textStatus + "\r\n" + "errorThrown: " + errorThrown);
                    }
                });
            }

            $('#fuelTicketsGrid').jqGrid({
                jsonReader: { root: 'tkts', repeatitems: true },
                width: 'auto',
                height: 'auto',
                autowidth: true,
                rownumbers: false,
                rownumWidth: 30,
                rowNum: 10, 
                rowList: [5, 10],
                edit: false,
                viewRecords: true,
                gridview: true,
                caption: "Fuel Tickets",
                pager: '#GridPager',
                onCellSelect: function (rowid, iCol, cellcontent) {
                    var grid = $('#fuelTicketsGrid');
                    var imageID = grid.jqGrid('getCell', rowid, 'Image_ID');
                    if (imageID != "")
                        DisplayReceipt(imageID);
                },
                colModel: [
                    { name: 'FuelTkt_ID', label: 'ID', width: 20, align: "right" },
                    { name: 'Ticket_No', label: 'Ticket', width: 60, align: "right" },
                    { name: 'Customer_Name', label: 'Customer', width: 150 },
                    { name: 'Vehicle_No', label: 'Vehicle', width: 60 },
                    { name: 'Trans_Timestamp', label: 'Date', width: 100, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'l, F d, Y g:i:s A' } },
                    { name: 'Image_ID', label: 'Image ID', width: 150 },
                ]
            });
            $('#fuelTicketsGrid').jqGrid('navGrid', '#GridPager', { add: false, edit: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: false });
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see a couple of issues.  Firstly your JSON isn't in the correct format.  It requires a couple of header fields that tells the grid how to render.  This is from their documentation:

```
{ total: xxx, page: yyy, records: zzz, rows: [ 
{name1:”Row01″,name2:”Row 11″,name3:”Row 12″,name4:”Row 13″,name5:”Row 14″}, ... ]}
```

Secondly, I don't know if how you've done it will work, but I used a normal ActionResult call to get my data in the controller:

```
    public ActionResult GetGrid()
    {
        YourEntities db = new YourEntities();
        int page = int.Parse(Request.Params["page"]);
        int rp = int.Parse(Request.Params["rows"]);

        // Whatever method to get your total rows, divide by page size
        int total = (db.SomeModels.Count() / rp) + 1;

        // Populate your List
        IEnumerable<SomeViewModel> rows = db.SomeModels.OrderBy(p => p.Name).Select(p => new SomeViewModel
        {
            ID = p.ID,
            Name = p.Name,
            Description = p.Description,
        }).Skip((page - 1) * rp).Take(rp);

        JsonResult retVal = Json(new { page, total, rows }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        return retVal;
    }
```

Lastly, I use a few differences in my Ajax call in jQuery:

```
    jQuery("#Grid").jqGrid({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetGrid", "Home")', 
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: "GET",
        cache: false,
        colNames: ['ID', 'Name', 'Description'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'ID', width: 90, sortable: true, align: 'left', show: false },
            { name: 'Name', width: 320, sortable: true, align: 'left' },
            { name: 'Description', width: 320, sortable: true, align: 'left' },
        ],
        rowNum: 20,
        rowList: [20, 50, 100],
        pager: '#GridPager',
        sortname: 'Name',
        height: '550px',
        width: 850,
        edit: false,
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "desc",
        jsonReader: {
            repeatitems: false,
            id: "0"
        },
    });
```

This is what worked for me, anyway :)

[Edit]

See above with more detail on returning your list in Linq.